# Фоновый процесс в приложении на android

Tags: java, android

Пишу небольшую утилиту под android. Назначение - чистка мусора, удаление ненужных файлов и тд. Вопрос можно ли запустить приложение в фоновом(свернутом) режиме что бы пользователь открыл один раз, поставил метод очистки `автоматически` и больше не открывал. Можно ли такое осуществить и если можно то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из последних и рекомендуемых Google решений - это использование FirebaseJobDispatcher:

> https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android
>   http://www.discoversdk.com/blog/android-guide-to-firebase-jobdispatcher

С его помощью можно создавать отложенные и повторяющиеся таски, плюс регулировать условия выполнения различными триггерами.

Есть еще вариант использовать `AlarmManager` (его использовали раньше, чтобы реализовать выполнение операций в конкретное время).

Либо самый просто вариант, но не рекомендуемый - просто `IntentService` и там просто усыплять поток на нужное время, а при пробуждении запускать Вашу очистку.

Comment: С помощью `FirebaseJobDispatcher` можно выполнять операции не уведомляя пользователя или обязательно что бы он их подтвердил? Просто в приложении должна быть такая опция что бы по 15 раз не спрашивать разрешения на чистку реестра, или каждый раз после установки/удалении нового приложения.

Comment: Можно без уведомления. Просто как фоновая задача

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: Решение *из пушки по воробьям* конечно.

Comment: Какую альтернативу предлагаете?

Comment: Например, вариант от @Magic - вполне себе

Comment: Тогда другой вопрос: чем хуже мое решение? Автору нужно делать очистку фоном. Диспетчер будет регистрировать таску в `AlarmManager`. Насколько я знаю, такой механизм не приводит к созданию новых потоков в приложении (как в случае с `ExecutorService`). Диспетчер ориентирован на экономию ресурсов при выполнении фоновых задач.

Comment: ExecutorService вполне себе экономичен в использовании, главное правильно подобрать  параметры. Говорю исходя из практики, где у меня отдельно 3 потока, в них выполняются в 1-м потоке каждые 300мс, 2-м - 10 сек., 3-м каждой сек. Даже на слабых и загруженных смартфонах не наблюдается какой-либо загрузки. При том, что задачи там достаточно тяжелые

Answer (score 0):

`ScheduledExecutorService` вам в помощь. При выборе  режима просто поднимайте сервис с необходимым вам интервалом (`scheduleAtFixedRate`) и будет вам счастье

Comment: Только надо посадить его в `Service` или `IntentService`

Comment: 1. прочитайте еще раз, там написано, что "просто поднимайте сервис".
2. смысл поднимать интент сервивс для такой задачи? , уж лучше тогда его использовать внутри ScheduledExecutorService